# Number of ways to arrange $m$ segments

Tags: combinatorics

I am wondering if the following problem has already been approached.

> Given a unit length $l$, a segment of length $L$, integer, is also given (call it the master segment), as well as $m$ segments of lengths $m_i$, $i$ running from $1$ to $m$ and all the $m_i$ integer too. The length of all m segments is less than the master segment
>
> The latter segments can be placed on the segment long $N$ only in such a way that the unit length long interval overlap (in other words, each segment can start and finish only at integer values of length of the master segment).
>
> How many ways are there to place all the $m$ segments?

Comment: Can you add some information about the $m$ segments - specifically, how does their total length compare to the length of the master segment?

Comment: Joffan, their total lenght is less than the length of the master segment. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the $m$ segments can be chosen in $m!$ ways, assuming the segments are distinguishable.

For each such choice, we then have to allocate the spare space: define $s = L - \sum {m_i}$. This can be allocated using a "stars & bars"-type calculation, choosing which are the spaces from a string of $(s+m)$ items, ${s+m \choose s}$.

Total number of choices over these two steps then is $$m!{s+m \choose s}$$